# Windows Mobile 6.5 Remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-mobile-6

I am trying to help a friend out, we have gotten him able to connect via his windows mobile 6.5 phone to his computer via remote desktop.  The problem we are running into is that the program that he needs to be able to access does not work at lower resolutions (such as his phone has) and most of the program screen is cut off (it is a VB program)  Is there a way to have a "higher" resolution on the screen being sent to the Windows Mobile 6.5 phone and just have him scroll up and down on the screen?

Right now replacing the phone is not an option (it might be 6 months down the line, but for now it is not an option).

Comment: The person I was helping with this has since gotten a new phone (android) and the issue is no longer relevent, I request a mod to close this question as it no longer is relevent.  And as WM 6.5 and older phones slowing going out of usage.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a year since I had my WM6.5 phone, but what program are you using to do remote desktop?  I remember using the standard program and it had an option to either scale the screen down to the resolution of the phone, connect at a specific resolution, or leave the resolution the same as the host.

If the program in question doesn't work the phone resolution, try to connect at a higher resolution so the program works.  (Obviously you would then have to deal with "scrolling" the desktop on the phone to get to the different edges of the screen)

Best of luck,
Mike